# Do cards that say "Each player..." still affect players with Shroud?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [True Believer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=True%20Believer) out which gives me shroud. My opponent has an enchantment that says that each player must sacrifice whenever he sacrifices a card. Does the enchantment target me, thus allowing me to avoid the effect, or does the enchantment still have its effect despite me having shroud?

Answer (score 12):

"Shroud" means "This permanent or player can't be the target of spells or abilities."

Unless the ability specifically uses the word *target*, it is not affected by *shroud*.

I'm not sure which enchantment you are talking about, but if it says *each player*, like [Grave Pact](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grave%20Pact), then it is not affected by shroud. If it says *target opponent* or *target player*, then it is affected by shroud.

Note that there is a subtype of Enchantment, [Curse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&subtype=+%5B%22Curse%22%5D), which have the line *Enchant Player*. These Enchantment Aura spells do target a player when they are on the stack, so they are affected by *shroud*.

Comment: If a True Believer is cast subsequently to a player being enchanted by a Curse, that wouldn't cause the Curse to fall off, am I right? Or am I confused?

Comment: @thesunneversets Auras target something only when the spell is on the stack. If a [Zur the Enchanter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=121162), for example, puts the Curse on the battlefield, it will not be affected by Shroud. see CR 303.4a and 303.4f

Comment: Good, that's what I thought.  I saw some potential for confusion in "...and are attached to player, so they are affected by Shroud".  Being attached to a player doesn't actually interact very much with Shroud at all, except insofar as usually things become attached via targeting (?)

Comment: @thesunneversets That's a good point and I shall reword my answer.

Comment: @thesunneversets yes, as per CR303.4a things are attached via targeting.

Comment: I would further clairify it with, "when these Enchantment Auras are spells"

Comment: or "when the enchantments are being cast" or something. In any case I think it would be a useful clarification.

Comment: I thought at first the word "spells" would be enough, but I added the caveat "when they are on the stack" so hopefully that's clear enough.

Answer (score 5):

If you have [True Believer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTrue%20Believer%5d) out, you have shroud. You cannot be the target of spells or abilities.

If a spell like [Grave Pact](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrave%20Pact%5d) comes along, you still must sacrifice, because you are not a target. As an analogy, [Mist Leopard](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMist%20Leopard%5d) still dies to [Day of Judgment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDay%20of%20Judgment%5d).

If a spell like [Curse of Bloodletting](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCurse%20of%20Bloodletting%5d) comes along, you're safe because the Aura targets you by definition (CR303.4a), but you are an illegal target. You're also safe from [Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d) and its ilk.